# HandleClick inside and outside of DOM Element

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I want to close the menu when there's a click on `<Burger />` and when there's a click outside `<Burger />`. With my current code only the click outside `<Burger />` will be handled, but the click on `<Burger />` will not close the menu.

When I reverse `domNode` to `!domNode` in the `handleClickOutside` function, clicking inside `<Burger />` works, but clicking outside `<Burger />` will no longer close the menu. Also I tried adding other conditions to the `handleClickOutside` function and that did not work also.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

```html
export class NavBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            change: false
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

        this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true);
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(state => ({
            change: !state.change
        }));
    }

    handleClickOutside(event) {
        const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

        if(domNode || !domNode.contains(event.target)){
            this.setState(state=> ({
                change: false
            }))
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="mobile">
                    <Menu change={this.state.change} onClickOutside={this.handleClickOutside} />
                    <nav>
                        <Burger change={this.state.change} onClick={this.handleClick} />
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>   
        )
    }
}
```

```
<Burger />
```

```html
export class Burger extends React.Component {  
    render(){
        return(
                <a className={classnames('burger', {'change': this.props.change})} onClick={this.props.onClick}> 
                    <div/>
                    <div/>
                    <div/>
                </a>
            
        )
    }
}
```

```
<Menu />
```

```html
export class Menu extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
        <div className={classnames({change: !this.props.change})}>
                <div className="menu" onClick={this.props.onClickOutside}>
                    <Link> 
                    </Link>
                   <Link>
                    </Link>
                </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure since i haven't all your code, but I have a guess.
You added an event listener in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true);
}
```

With this code, depending on how `Burger` handle its `onClick` props, this may happen:

1. You click inside the `Burger`; its `onClick` is triggered which calls the `props.onClick` and thus you call the `handleClick` of `NavBar`;
2. Then, since the event propagates, it reaches the `handleClickOutside`, and that's because the event has reached the `document`. So, since you call `handleClickOutside`, inside of it you switch again the state.

Again, this is all a guess I'm having. If you wanna test this you can use the debug and notice if, when clicking inside the `Burger`, you reach both `onClick` and `handleClickOutside`.

Anyways, it would be appreciated the code of both `Burger` and `Menu` because we cannot know what is happening in there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added both Burger & Menu

Comment: Ok, it's difficult since your example is not working, it's just bunch of code :) Anyways, I tried to reproduce your code and it seems to me it happens what I described in the answer: when you write `document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true);` you are adding a click listener on the whole document. When you click on the `Burger`, your `handleOnClick` is triggered due to the click on the `Burger`, but the same event reaches the `handleClickOutside`. Eventually, since both are runned, you end up changing the state twice, and it seems to you that no clickwas made on `Burger`